# Is it bad practice when an Object has to be aware of another Object

Tags: java, object-oriented, class-design, abstraction

I was reading [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350162/what-is-the-benefit-to-having-pure-poco-models) and came across [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350164/315575) sentence in the accepted answer:

> I don't like `A` directly knowing about `B`. But that's a DIP thing
>   not a POJO thing.

What if you can't abstract out `B` so that `A` isn't aware of it?

Suppose if I have the following `Book` class:

```
public final class Book {

    private final Author author;

    // constructor and methods left out :D. 
} 


public final Author {

     private final String firstName;
     private final String lastName;

     // constructor and methods left out :D.
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that a book might have a list of authors, so it would be better if it was `List<Author> authors`, but I want to focus on a specific part of the above code sample.

Some might point out that the `Book` class knows about the `Author` object.

I don't see why `Author` would be an `interface` or `abstract` class.

**Question:**

Would you abstract out `Author`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that in your example the `Book` class depends on `Author`, it's quite plausible that `Author` depends on `Country`, `Town` and `Language` (describing home town and native language), and so on.

For the productive use of the program, you'll probably need `Books` with `Authors` having all these properties. So, there's nothing really wrong about that approach.

But if you want to unit-test some functionality about `Books`, you'll appreciate not having to construct full-fledged `Authors` with their `Country`, `Town` and `Language` instances (and their dependencies and so on). Instead you'll want to use mockups with just enough functionality to support the `Book` class.

To make that easy, define as an interface the API that an `Author` offers to other classes (hopefully `Book` and e.g. `PublishingCompany` need similar methods from `Author`, otherwise you should create multiple interfaces). Then for testing purposes, you (or your preferred mocking framework) can supply `Author`-like objects that are sufficient for `Book`, but don't need all the other classes.

Of course, there are situations where this is just over-engineering, e.g. if `Author` really is nothing more than a holder for first and last name.

Answer (score 2):

Whether we want to use an abstraction(interfaces and abstract classes) depends on whether we want the following advantages :

- We want to be able to comfortably switch between different implementations of `Author` like `ScientificJournalAuthor` or `FictionAuthor` or a `AutoBiographyAuthor`. If all these different authors follow the contract of the interface `Author`, you will be able to use them interchangeably in certain scenarios, reaping the benefits of code reuse.
- By thinking in terms of an Abstraction, you will be able to narrow down on the minimal amount of functionality you need from an `Author` for the `Book` class. This knowledge will help you keep your implementation of `Book` decoupled from implementations of `Author`.

Warning : Make sure you don't spawn too many abstractions as this can reduce code readability and make you spend time thinking about things that aren't necessary and provide little code reuse.

Comment: This answer provides a good example of why in this case, the more general reasoning it that this approach make the software more flexible with regard to enhancement and is closely related to the Open Closed principle  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle

Comment: The problem is, I don't see why different subclasses of Author need to exist. The types you provide in your first point could just as easily be stored in a `List` collection called `genres`, to indicate that one author might write multiple types of books.

Comment: @BasementJoe This is getting contrived because this example is conflating data and functionality, but imagine that the company's ID for an author has a unique prefix depending on their main genre.  If you have a `mainGenre` property, you need one function for `GetPrefix` that has a big switch-case statement depending on their `mainGenre`, that has to be updated anytime a new genre comes out or any prefix is changed.  On the other hand, with different subclasses all implementing their own `GetPrefix`, it's easy to add a new genre or update an existing one with minimal chance of impact.

Comment: @BasementJoe I see your concern. Let me elaborate on the scenario I was trying to highlight. Assume you have a method `findLastElement(List list)`. Here `List` is an interface that can either be substituted by an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, making this method more general than if it was `findLastElement(ArrayList list)` instead.