# Does using primitive types instead of user-defined types reduce dependencies?

Tags: code-smell

Suppose I have a member function `void A::foo(B const &b)` where a `class B` instance is just a bunch of data. Would it not be better to remove the dependency between `class A` and `class B` by rewriting the member function like `void A::foo(int var1, double var2, double var3)`? Or could this modification be classified as a [Primitive Obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession)?

Comment: Wether a class or method depends on a primitive type or a custom value type, it still has the same number of dependencies. Replacing custom value types with primitives is a step in the wrong direction and definitely an example of primitive obsession.

Comment: this is a pattern, and one of the good ones. see this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318226/should-we-avoid-custom-objects-as-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which way the dependency goes. You do not want some library to depend on types in your application, this would defeat the purpose of having a library. But as long as the richer type's definition is in the library itself, this would just be regarded as strong typing, which is a good thing.

Comment: Good point! What would be your recommendations if both class A and class B are not library types but application types?

Comment: As long as they are in the same module there is no issue. If not, you would have to ask yourself whether it is OK for module A to depend on module B or not. You may want to introduce module C that serves both A and B so A and B can stay independent of each other. Or you may want to keep everything in the same module. It all depends on what purpose you have in mind for each module.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type like a struct if it is already available, and it matches the logic of the parameters. You wouldn’t use a random unrelated struct containing an Int and a double to replace two parameters.